# Inheritance of Iterable

Tags: java

I have a class `Super` and class `Sub` where `Sub extends Super`.

I'm trying to write a class which contains a list of Sub but must implement `Iterable<Super>`. What I tried to to is:

```
class Bag implements Iterable<Super> {
     List<Sub> list;

     public Iterator<Super> iterator() {
          return list.iterator();
     }
 }
```

This doesn't compile (the error message is `Cannot cast from Iterator<Sub> to Iterator<Super>`). I tried casting in several places, and wildcards in other places, but I don't see what's the problem. I certainly don't see why

```
public Iterator<Super> iterator() {
    return (Iterator<Super>)list.iterator();
}
```

wouldn't cast. It's possible that 
[java iterator/iterable subinterface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374671/java-iterator-iterable-subinterface) has the solution, but I don't understand it.

///// UPDATE

I managed to do it this way:

```
Iterator<? extends Super> iterator = ((List<? extends Super>)list).iterator();
return (Iterator<Super>)iterator;
```

(which gives a warning, `Type safety: Unchecked cast from Iterator<capture#4-of ? extends Super> to Iterator<Super>`. I can live with it, but why does it give this warning?)

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: "Cannot cast from Iterator<Sub> to Iterator<Super>"

Comment: Generics don't let you do that...

Comment: Not exactly, @Dennis. The question you mention is more theoretic, and it doesn't explain why casting twice works, but casting once doesn't.

Comment: I don't agree that what I linked is more theoretic, but I do concede that I didn't see it address why the double casting would work.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using java 8 an easy way to do this is:

```
class Bag implements Iterable<Super> {
    List<Sub> list;

    public Iterator<Super> iterator() {
        return list.stream().map(s -> (Super)s).iterator();
    }
}
```

Comment: OP's own solution avoids making `Bag` generic.

Comment: @VF1 I've changed my answer to more closely reflect OP's code, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

> I certainly don't see why
>
> ```
> List<Sub> list;
>
> public Iterator<Super> iterator() {
>     return (Iterator<Super>)sections.iterator();
> }
> ```
>
> wouldn't cast.

Consider situation where you have classes `Fruit` `Apple` `Banana`. You have list of `Fruit`s

```
List<Fruit> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

so you can add to it any kind of fruit like `Apple` or `Banana`.

```
list.add(new Apple());
list.add(new Banana());
```

Now would it be safe to cast such list to more specified type, lets say list of `Apple`s? No. Why? Consider following example:

```
List<Apple> apples = (List<Apple>)list; //lets assume for now that this is OK
for (Apple ap : apples){
    //do something with apple
}
```

But `list` contains not only `Apple`s but also `Banana`, which is not right argument for code in `for` loop.

You to solve this problem in many ways, for instance you can try using wildcards like `List<? extends Super>`. It all depends on what you are actually trying to achieve.

### Response to your update

```
List<Sub> list;

public Iterator<Super> iterator() {
    Iterator<? extends Super> iterator = ((List<? extends Super>)list).iterator();
    return (Iterator<Super>)iterator;
}
```

Is same as

```
public Iterator<Super> iterator() {
    List<? extends Super> tmp = list;                     //1
    Iterator<? extends Super> iterator = tmp.iterator();  //2
    return (Iterator<Super>) iterator;                    //3
}
```

In line marked `//1` you are creating temporary reference of type `List<? extends Super>` and use it to handle `list` which is type `List<Sub>` which is perfectly fine, because `<? extends Super>` was meant to hold type which extends `Super` like in this case `Sub`.

In line `//2` you are creating iterator using `tmp` reference so you are getting iterator with same generic type as this reference so it is `Iterator<? extends Super>`.

Now problem can happen here

```
return (Iterator<Super>) iterator;                    //3
```

Consider situation:
You have `List<? extends Super>` and you want to cast it to `List<Super>`. Would that be safe? Not really, because via `List<Super>` you would be able to add any instance of `Super` type and its subtypes, like `SubFoo` or `SubBar`. It means that if `List<? extends Super>` would hold `List<SubBar>` you would be able to add to this list not only desired `SubBar` but also `SubFoo`, which is potentially dangerous. That is why compiler will inform you about potential danger.

Interestingly this time you will not see compilation error, but warning. It is probably because explicitly casting `List<Sub>` to `List<Super>` is to big shortcut which could lead to misunderstandings because programmers could forget what wrong could happen.

Using casting from wildcard may demonstrate that you understand generics enough to say "OK compiler, I am aware of possible problems you want to protect me from, but I know what I am doing", that is why you are seeing warning instead of compilation error.

Comment: But I _know_ it is a list of apples. I just want to tell the compiler it is.

Comment: @ModdyFire You know, but compiler doesn't, so it assumes that since there is risk such code shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: Also, it lets me cast the list (see first line) but wouldn't let me cast the iterator. I have an iterator of apples. I want to iterate over fruit - there cannot be an issue.